# How to pivot on a column in BigQuery without knowing values beforehand?

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot, pivot-table

I've got a table which looks like:

```
| id|cat|elems |
|---|---|------|
| 1 | A |[a, b]|
| 1 | B |[b, c]|
| 2 | C |[b, c]|
```

Where `elems` is an array column.

Is there a way I can pivot on the `cat` column without hardcoding the values of `cat` (so not doing a `CASE`/`IF` on `cat='A'`, etc)?
The desired result would look like:

```
| id| A    | B    |   C  |
|---|------|------|------|
| 1 |[a, b]|[b, c]| NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL |[b, c]|
```

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery doesn't have a `PIVOT` function. You can look how to simulate pivoting in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#pivottable).

Also I would suggest you to take a look at those two Stack Overflow questions:

1. [How to Pivot in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715007/How%20to%20Pivot%20in%20Google%20BigQuery/30716063)
2. [Transpose rows into columns in BigQuery (Pivot implementation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761453/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-bigquery-pivot-implementation)

Comment: Seems like there's no way around hardcoding the cases